# How to enlarge zeros in the tkz-tab package?

Tags: tkz-tab

In this code how can I enlarge the zeros? The documentation is in German and I don't know the German language.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit[espcl=1.5]
{$x$ / 1 ,$f(x)$ /1 }%
{$v_1$ , $v_2$ , $v_3$ }%
\tkzTabLine{ z, , z , ,z }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You really think that the documentation is in German? ;-) It's French, actually!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Ha Ha Ha:-) Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: What do you mean by "enlarge the zeros" ?

Comment: @salimbou: I want the zeros to be a little bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can for example patch the command `\tkzTabLine` using [`xpatch`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) package, and change the line of code

```
\node at (Z\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg){$0$};
```

With

```
\node[font=\Large] at (Z\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg){$0$};
```

To change the size of font inside node containing zeros

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\tkzTabLine}
{\node at (Z\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg){$0$};} % search
{\node[font=\Large] at (Z\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg){$0$};} % replace
{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit[espcl=1.5]
{$x$ / 1 ,$f(x)$ /1 }%
{$v_1$ , $v_2$ , $v_3$ }%
\tkzTabLine{z , , z , ,z }

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]