# How to create more options for \tkzTabLine?

Tags: packages, xpatch, tkz-tab

I use `\usepackage{tkz-tab}` to create sign tables. For example, to determine the solutions of the inequality below we use the table:
[image]

which is generated by the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-tab}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit[lgt=3,espcl=2]
{/1.2, $5x-1$ /.8, $x+3$ /.8, $\dfrac{5x-1}{x+3}$ /1.2} % first column
{$-\infty$,$-3$,$\dfrac{1}{5}$,$\infty$} % first row
\tkzTabLine { ,-,t,-,z,+, } % second row
\tkzTabLine {,-,z,+,t,+,} % third row
\tkzTabLine {,+,d,-,z,+,} % last row
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When a function is undefined at a certain value, instead of using the option d in the last row of the table `\tkzTabLine {,+,d,-,z,+,}`
I use `\tkzTabLine {,+,${\tiny DNE}$,-,z,+,}` where DNE stands for it does not exist.

However, I would like to have a new option, say `u`, where `u` does whatever the option `z` does (with the vertical line of dots included), but instead of having a `$0$`, I would like to have a box with `${\tiny DNE}$` inside. Then I would just need to use `\tkzTabLine {,+,u,-,z,+,}` for the last row.

Could you please help me with this?

---

**UPDATE:** In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/318816/81269) it is shown how the `$0$` in the definition of the option `z`is modified by using `\xpatchcmd`.

In the code of the package `tkz-tab`([see here](https://github.com/tkz-sty/tkz-tab/blob/master/latex/tkz-tab.sty)) the definition of option `z` can be found in line 432.

I have tried to insert the following definition of the new option `u` by copying the definition of `z`and modifying it. However, it does not compile. It mentions something about the brace } was missing.

For reference, here is the definition of the option `z`:

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\expandafter\stripspaces\expandafter{\x}}{z}}{%
     \draw[line width = \cmdTAB@tbs@lw,t style]%
          (N\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg) -- %
          (N\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lgnext);
          \node at (Z\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg){$0$};
```

Here is the option `u` that I would like to implement, so far without succes:

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\expandafter\stripspaces\expandafter{\x}}{u}}{%
     \draw[line width = \cmdTAB@tbs@lw,t style]%
          (N\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg) -- %
          (N\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lgnext);
          \node at (Z\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg){$DNE$};
```

---

**UPDATE 2:** Thanks to @gernot I got what I wanted:
[image]
through the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}% for \dfrac
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\tkzTabLine{%
  \path (N\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg)--%
  (N\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lgnext); 
  \node at (Z\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg){$\x$};
}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\expandafter\stripspaces\expandafter{\x}}{u}}{%
     \draw[line width = \cmdTAB@tbs@lw,double style,double distance=3pt]%
       (N\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg) -- %
       (N\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lgnext);
     \node at (Z\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg){
     \begin{tcolorbox}                      
     [width=0.85cm,boxsep=0pt,left=2pt,right=2pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt]
     \scriptsize DNE
     \end{tcolorbox}};
  }{%
    \path (N\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg)--%
    (N\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lgnext); 
    \node at (Z\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg){$\x$};
  }%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit[lgt=2,espcl=1.6]
{/1, $5x-1$ /.8, $x+3$ /.8, $\dfrac{5x-1}{x+3}$ /1.2} % first column
{$-\infty$,$-3$,$\dfrac{1}{5}$,$\infty$} % first row
\tkzTabLine { ,-,t,-,z,+, } % second row
\tkzTabLine {,-,z,+,t,+,} % third row
\tkzTabLine {,+,u,-,z,+,} % last row
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you try to modify is a sequence of nested if-then-else statements. To add another option, you have to insert not just another if-then, but also another final closing parenthesis.

```
\ifthenelse{cond 1}{%
  % then 1
}{% else 1
  \ifthenelse{cond 2}{%
    % then 2
  }{% else 2
    ...
        }{% else n-1
          \ifthenelse{cond n}{%
            % then n
          }{% else n
            ...
}}...}}% number of closing parentheses = number of else branches = number of \ifthenelses
```

In the `\tkzTabLine` command, we replace the last else-branch by another if-then-else, where the old else-branch becomes the new else-branch.

```
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\tkzTabLine{%
  \path (N\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg)--%
  (N\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lgnext); 
  \node at (Z\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg){$\x$};
}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\expandafter\stripspaces\expandafter{\x}}{u}}{%
     \draw[line width = \cmdTAB@tbs@lw,t style]%
       (N\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg) -- %
       (N\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lgnext);
     \node at (Z\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg){\footnotesize$DNE$};
  }{%
    \path (N\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg)--%
    (N\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lgnext); 
    \node at (Z\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg){$\x$};
  }%
}{}{}
\makeatother
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% for \dfrac
\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\tkzTabLine{%
  \path (N\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg)--%
  (N\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lgnext); 
  \node at (Z\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg){$\x$};
}{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\expandafter\stripspaces\expandafter{\x}}{u}}{%
     \draw[line width = \cmdTAB@tbs@lw,t style]%
       (N\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg) -- %
       (N\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lgnext);
     \node at (Z\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg){\footnotesize$DNE$};
  }{%
    \path (N\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg)--%
    (N\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lgnext); 
    \node at (Z\thetkz@cnt@impair\thetkz@cnt@lg){$\x$};
  }%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzTabInit[lgt=3,espcl=2]
{/1.2, $5x-1$ /.8, $x+3$ /.8, $\dfrac{5x-1}{x+3}$ /1.2} % first column
{$-\infty$,$-3$,$\dfrac{1}{5}$,$\infty$} % first row
\tkzTabLine { ,-,t,-,z,+, } % second row
\tkzTabLine {,-,z,+,t,+,} % third row
\tkzTabLine {,+,u,-,z,+,} % last row
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```